# Protractor test cases not running in headless mode

Tags: selenium, protractor, headless

Protractor test cases are running fine with browser open but not in headless mode.

I have tried running protractor test cases different selectors and sleep browser approaches but it doesn't work in headless mode in any way.
I am running it with docker setup.

```
it('should show profile link', async function() {


await action.waitForSelector(map.homePage.my_profile, config.credentials.min_timeout);


await action.checkElementPresent(map.homePage.my_profile, 'profile link');
    });


Error: should show profile link

       Failed: Did not find element: .my-profile

       Wait timed out after 2000ms

       Wait timed out after 2000ms
```

It gives the above error on asserting the selector and it works fine if tests are run with browser open. It is not able to find selector in headless mode.

Comment: plus, the '.my-profile' is the selector of 'class' type.

Comment: the question is too broad. As a suggestion, try to narrow down the results by taking screenshots when failing. Run headless but locally, not in docker. Configure debugging configuration and run commands manually one by one

Comment: What kind of headless? What browser? With directConnect? With selenium jar file? Is this with Docker? What version are you using of Protractor and what version of node are you using? What configuration arguments are you passing in your configuration? What is the object action and what does checkElementPresent and waitForSelector look like?

Comment: We need to know your config files in order to see if it is implemented properly.

Answer (score 1):

set you browserOption under capabilities like below mentioned snippet in your conf.js- It might help

```
chromeOptions: {
        args: ['--headless', '--no-sandbox', '--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--disable-browser-side-navigation', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--disable-gpu', '--ignore-certificate-errors', '--ignore-ssl-errors', '--disable-infobars=true'],
    }
```